# Running command line in unix via Java

Tags: java, shell, unix, command-line

I have some problem. When I run the command:

```
openssl md5 "./build/outputs/apk/myApp.apk"
```

I get the result that I need, so openssl works fine.
Then there is my code in Java:

```
String md5_cmd = "openssl md5 \"./build/outputs/apk/myApp.apk\"";

String md5Str = obj.executeCommand(md5_cmd);
String whichCmd = obj.executeCommand("which openssl"); //For testing executeCommand

 System.out.println(md5Str); //Not prints anything  
 System.out.println(whichCmd); //Prints the result just Fine    

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

So, the first command with "md5_cmd" not showing any output, although if I run it directly via command line its OK. The second command with "whichCmd" works as expected. Can you advise?

Comment: Please note, this code works well under Windows, but not on UNIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running command with a single string

```
String md5_cmd = "openssl md5 \"./build/outputs/apk/myApp.apk\"";
```

Commands with arguments shall be run by using String[]

```
String[] md5_cmd = {"openssl", "md5", "./build/outputs/apk/myApp.apk"};
```

Comment: Not in case of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

Comment: Please see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]))

Comment: please see sources instead, http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Runtime.java#l446. Or, if you want, javadoc to another method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String) - More precisely, the <code>command</code> string is broken into tokens using aStringTokenizer created by the call new StringTokenizer(command) with no further modification of the character categories.  The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array cmdarray, in the same order